# Can't initialize physical volume of volume group without -ff

Tags: lvm

```
Can't initialize physical volume "/dev/sda3" of volume group "stark" without -ff
```

I created physical volume with `pvcreate` followed by `vgcreate` and `lvcreate` successfully. Later on, I deleted in reverse order `lvdelete`, `vgdelete`, `pvdelete`.Now I got this error when I would like to create `pvcreate` after making new partition.

I appreciate if you could let me know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue. In my case the old VG was still present.

See if old volume group is preset with `vgdisplay`.

Remove group with `vgremove -f <vg_name>`

Answer (score 3):

If you are absolutely sure the PV isn't being used then just go ahead and do what it tells you

```
pvcreate -ff /dev/sd...
```